# i am not able to change roleid of user before saving user data i want to change his role id to 2 and save

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am saving new user with his company name if that companay is new then i have to set his roleid to 2(manager) else 1 by default.

here is my code

```
Users.findOne({companyName:req.body.companyName},function(err,companyFound){
    if(err){
      console.log('error while fnding company name:'+err)
      return res.json({result:false,msg:err});
    }
    else if(!companyFound){
      console.log('company name not found :'+req.body.companyName);
       Users.findOne({username:req.body.username},function(err,userfound){
    if(err){
      console.log(err)
      return res.status(500).send('error while signup'+err)
    }
    if(!userfound){
      console.log("============================");
      console.log('ok... this is unique username : ' + req.body.username)
      user.roleId = 2;  /// setting roleid to 2/// problem here
      console.log('log before saving manager'+user);
      user.save(function(err,managersaved){
        if(err){
          console.log('error while saving signup manager data'+err);
          return res.json({result:false,msg:err});
        }
        else if(managersaved){
          console.log('guys we have new manager');
          return res.json({result:false,Data:managersaved});
        }
      })

    }
```

and here is user variable

```
    var user = new Users({
    username: req.body.username,
    name: req.body.name,
    mobile: req.body.mobile,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
    managerId: req.body.managerId,
    roleId: req.body.roleId,
    companyName: req.body.companyName
  });
```

Comment: what is the question here?

Comment: i am not able to change roleid of user before saving user data i want to change his role id to 2 and save it.

Comment: did you try by setting `req.body.roleId` to `2`?

Comment: no, if new company is created then i manually want to it save value 2 instead of 1 because i created in schema default value is 1.

Comment: Ok, solved i was looking old function this is working well.